# Merge repos for redis to work on Openshift

Tags: git, merge, redis, openshift

I am trying to get redis to work on OpenShift by following this git repos readme (https://github.com/EddyRespondek/redis-standalone-openshift-example/blob/master/README.md)

The problem is that I keep erroring out with the last command as follows

> git pull -s recursive -X myAppGitRepoSSHString upstream master
>   From git://github.com/EddyRespondek/redis-standalone-openshift-example
>
> * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
>   fatal: Unknown option for merge-recursive: -XmyAppRepoSSHString

And if I try with patience

> git pull -s recursive -X patience myAppGitRepoSSHString upstream master
>
> fatal: Couldn't find remote ref upstream
>
> fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

I am replacing myAppGitRepoSSHString with the SSH string/key that openshift gives me when I put this in my terminal.
I am not familiar with the git cli as I should be so any help would be great.

Comment: When you say myAppGitRepoSSHString, you're replacing that with your app's actual git ssh url right? You're not actually typing that into the terminal?

Comment: Yeah I am replacing it with my actual SSH string. I didn't really feel like posting that here.

Comment: Edited original post to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument passed to the `-X` option should be `theirs` according to that page. You have to add that repository as a remote, for example named `upstream`:

```
git remote add upstream -m master git://github.com/EddyRespondek/redis-standalone-openshift-example.git
```

Now you can run the other command:

```
git pull -s recursive -X theirs upstream master
```

Exactly as it appears.

Comment: I am replacing it with the correct ssh url that openshift gives me. I updated my post for clarity.

Comment: ... ... ... ... ... Well that seems to work now. I tried that at the beginning of this ordeal and it didnt work. My friend just tried it like 1 min ago and then again now and it didnt work the first time but it did the second. Perhaps it was the sacrifice I made to the internet gods?